# Split/Explode Pandas column with dictionary entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
index          column1
e1             {u'c680': 5, u'c681': 1, u'c682': 2...
e2             {u'c780': 6, u'c781': 2, u'c782': 1...
e3             {u'c880': 2, u'c881': 4, u'c882': 2...
e4             {u'c980': 4, u'c981': 2, u'c982': 3...
```

Now I want to expand the dict in column1 to individual columns like below.

```
index   colname           c681
e1        c680              5
e1        c681              1
e1        c682              2
e2        c780              6
e2        c781              2
e2        c782              1
```

I went through couple of similar answers where it was suggested to use:

```
df.column1.apply(pd.Series)
```

But, this explode the column in different way...is there any way to achieve column shown better??

Comment: `pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(d) for d in df.column1)`.

Comment: Calling the constructor as many times as rows in the dataframe won't be very efficient @quang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten `Series` of dictionaries in list comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor, solution working if `index` in not column in input data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(k, ) + y for k, v in df.column1.items() for y in v.items()], 
                    columns=['idx','colname', 'c681'])
print (df1)
   idx colname  c681
0   e1    c680     5
1   e1    c681     1
2   e1    c682     2
3   e2    c780     6
4   e2    c781     2
5   e2    c782     1
6   e3    c880     2
7   e3    c881     4
8   e3    c882     2
9   e4    c980     4
10  e4    c981     2
11  e4    c982     3
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. My apologies, I had to edit my question as I missed minor thing in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the dictionaries with `dict.items`, flatten the resulting tuples with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and reconstruct the dataframe:

```
from itertools import chain

chained = chain.from_iterable(df.column1.map(dict.items))
pd.DataFrame(chained , columns=['colname', 'c681'])

  colname  c681
0    c680     5
1    c681     1
2    c682     2
3    c780     6
4    c781     2
5    c782     1
```

Comment: My apologies....I had missed minor thing in the question. So, I have edited it.

Comment: Editing the question might invalidate some of the current answers (as it does with mine, chaining does no longer work). I'd kindly encourage you to ask the question anew, otherwise it seems as the current answers are wrong @Rocky